# Why was my not an answer (NAA) flag declined?

Tags: discussion, answers, flags, declined-flags

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45964243/include-not-parsing-template-file/45965021#45965021) post of mine a user posted the following answer:

> For the sake of future readers... The `#include` directive never outputs itself like `<#include ...>` (so as you now know, it's `main.ftl` that's not passed to FreeMarker). Its `parse` parameter applies to the includ**ed** file. Also if a template is not found, it will throw an exception, not doing something arbitrary like printing `<#include ...>`.

I ultimately felt that it should not have been an answer as it does not actually help solve the issue (or come close for that matter) rather it informs people about the workings of the `#include` directive subsequently it should have been a comment. Yet my flag was declined:

[image]

For future references, why was my NAA flag declined so I don't make the same mistake or was it in fact declined incorrectly?

**Update**

This question is being closed as a potential duplicate yet my issue is that the answer that I've linked doesn't actually attempt to answer the question as mentioned above it is giving general information about the directive not what is causing the directive not to parse the content of the `.ftl` file.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553/7347933

Comment: @suraj my issue is that the answer that I've linked doesn't actually attempt to answer the question as mentioned above it is giving general information about the directive not what is causing the directive not to parse the content of the `.ftl` file.

Comment: @Script47 read carefully the duplicate, incorrect answer, even missing the mark, are to be downvoted, NAA are for thing not even close of an answer like "I've this problem too", "Thanks fo it"

Comment: @Script47: do you think that that is clear from reading just the answer? It's not obvious to me, just from seeing that answer, if it is a comment on something else or not. (Not the mod that handled the flag, but I can see why).

Comment: Answering a "what is the problem" by a "what it's not" is an try to answer. So still an answer.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I felt it was clear seeing as the answer started as *For the sake of future readers...[...]* which immediately shouts comment to me and that was before reading the rest of the content.

Comment: @Script47: you'd be surprised how many people write "I can't comment yet, but ..." before writing a valid answer to a question. We look at the post as a whole.

Comment: It's sound like a comment but it's a warning. To help people that are try to solve the issue to understand "where to look at" by explaining "where not to look".

Comment: @MartijnPieters No problem, understood. I merely wanted to know what could be done in the future (for either side) thanks for the help.

Comment: @DragandDrop thanks, understood.

Comment: In debugging things sometimes we can just eliminate things till we find why it's not working. Every body seem to be focus on "finding the Template", "is the Template there". He comes with this idea: 'if the template was missing there ll be an exception', If you want to validate this try to narrow the scope use a false path and see if an error is throw. And comment his answer with the result.